# WP_Query always returning the last custom post

Tags: wp-query, database, query, mysql

I have code that works fine on our live system, and I'm porting it to a new theme.  In the new theme, the WP_Query always seems to return the last custom post.

My function is:

```
    function get_wpinfo( $entry) {
        global $post;
        $resp_array = array();
        $args = array( 
            'posts_per_page'=> 1,
            'post_type'     => 'table_element',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_name'         => $entry       );
        print "Args = "; var_dump( $args );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            print_r( $post );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        return  $resp_array;
    }
```

The output from the first print is:

```
    Args = array(4) {
        ["posts_per_page"]=>  int(1)
        ["post_type"]=>  string(13) "table_element"
        ["post_status"]=>  string(7) "publish"
        ["post_name"]=>  string(2) "24"
    }
```

And the output from the print_r is:

```
    WP_Post Object
    (
        [ID] => 4239
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2015-08-25 19:00:44
        [post_date_gmt] => 2015-08-25 19:00:44
        [post_content] => Source: <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/5-predictions-predictive-analytics-2015-mark-rabkin" target="“_blank">5 Analytics Predictions 2015</a>
        [post_title] => 2
        [post_excerpt] => 
        [post_status] => publish
        [comment_status] => closed
        [ping_status] => closed
        [post_password] => 
        [post_name] => 2
        [to_ping] => 
        [pinged] => 
        [post_modified] => 2015-08-25 19:00:44
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2015-08-25 19:00:44
        [post_content_filtered] => 
        [post_parent] => 0
        [guid] => http://www.meshagency-salient.com.php53-17.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/?post_type=table_element&p=4239
        [menu_order] => 0
        [post_type] => table_element
        [post_mime_type] => 
        [comment_count] => 0
        [filter] => raw
    )
```

At first, the code was always returning the Custom Post with slug "99".  Then I realized, it was returning the last post created.  I deleted and re-created posts "1
 and "2" and now it always returns "2".

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `post_name` argument for `WP_Query`, if you're querying by slug, it's just `name`. Without that argument, your query just gets the latest post back.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you.  I can't believe I've been looking at this all day and missed that.